# Fractions with 3 diffferent variables

Tags: fractions

Calculate the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ if: $$\frac{5}{13} = \frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{2}{c}}}$$
Can anyone give me a hint and **not** the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Try out the online continued fraction calculator, it's fun and it will give you an answer to your problem : http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/cfCALC.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\dfrac{5}{13}=\dfrac{1}{a+\dfrac{c}{bc+2}}=\dfrac{bc+2}{a(bc+2)+c}\\
\implies a=\dfrac{13(bc+2)-5c}{5(bc+2)}=\dfrac{13}{5}-\dfrac{c}{bc+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just swing the terms at LHS and RHS as follows
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{5}{13} &= \frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{2}{c}}}\\
a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{2}{c}}&=\frac{13}{5}\\
\frac{1}{b+\frac{2}{c}}&=\frac{13}{5}-a\\
\frac{1}{b+\frac{2}{c}}&=\frac{13-5a}{5}\\
b+\frac{2}{c}&=\frac{5}{13-5a}\\
\frac{bc+2}{c}&=\frac{5}{13-5a}\\
(bc+2)(13-5a)&=5c.
\end{align}
$$
I think it is enough. The rest I leave it to you.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$